# mm_shuffle_epi8 equivalent on ARM machines

Tags: c, arm, neon, cortex-m, cortex-a8

In a project which is focussed on accelerating the performance on ARM,
I am using the mm_shuffle_epi8 implementation from the below page https://github.com/f4exb/cm256cc/blob/master/sse2neon.h#L981.

But above implementation is sub optimal and leading to performance costs.

Is there a right equivalent for _mm_shuffle_epi8  for ARM ?

Comment: My suggestion is that if you need this kind of performance you should probably do an Arm-specific implementation of the entire function. This way it is possible to change the algorithm to make fit better to the Arm instruction set.

Comment: @Johan I think the OP is doing an ARM-specific implementation, and is looking for clues. I myself learned `AVX2` with `NEON2SSE`.

Comment: You might be interested in [SIMD Everywhere}(https://github.com/simd-everywhere/simde). Along with its implementation, the wiki and documentation link to other implementations.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent should be something like

```
uint8x16_t shuffle_epi8(uint8x16_t table, uint8x16_t index) {
   int8x16_t mask = vshrq_n_s8(vreinterpretq_s8_u8(index), 7);
   index = vandq_u8(index, vdupq_n_u8(15));
   index = vqtbl1q_u8(table, index);
   return vbicq_u8(index, vreinterpretq_u8_s8(mask));
}
```

On armv7 one needs to emulate the 16-bit wide table by

```
inline uint8x16_t vqtbl1q_u8(uint8x16_t table, uint8x16_t idx) {
    uint8x8x2_t table2{vget_low_u8(table), vget_high_u8(table)};
    uint8x8_t lo = vtbl2_u8(table2, vget_low_u8(idx));
    uint8x8_t hi = vtbl2_u8(table2, vget_high_u8(idx));
    return vcombine_u8(lo, hi);
}
```

Comment: Do you see the `cortex-a8` tag? :-)

Comment: If the index vector is known to be within 0..15, then it's sufficient to use just the `vqtbl1q_u8` function.

Comment: You should put the msb check to make it 100% compliant. Yes, it sucks, and that's why I'm saying SSE2NEON isn't a good idea.

Comment: The MSB check has been there in the `shuffle_epi8` from the beginning. I'm using `vcltq_u8(index, 0x80);`, which converts to signed comparison with immediate. It doesn't need to be added to the `vqtbl1q_u8`, since that's only the arm64 emulation for armv7.

Comment: You don't need `vclt`. You just need signed `vshr` by 7, then `vbic`

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to skin a cat. I was also considering `vshrq_s8 + bic`, but wanted to avoid `reinterpretq`. I can be mistaken, but I think both methods are equally performant.

Comment: No, you need `vmov`, `vclt`, and `vand` while `vshr` and `vbic` will do the job the other way. And you might need one more register to load 0x80

Comment: On armv8, the sequence is anyway compiled to `vcgt reg, reg, #0; vand r,r,r`. I don't know if armv7 is missing that addressing mode. But changed anyway...

Answer (score 1):

`vtbl2` (and possibly `vtbx2`) is exactly what you are looking for.

But beware, these instructions come with a long latency, **especially on Cortex-a57 and Cortex-a72.** (`aarch64` mode) It doesn't even pipeline on the A-57.

I myself try to avoid them at all costs: too pricey.

NEON has superior permutation instructions over `AVX`. Maybe you can find a workaround.

PS: SSE2NEON.... not a good idea at all IMO. And the way the link you gave is doing is just horrible.

Comment: Thank you. Found the intrinsic vqtbl1q_u8 which is quivalent of shuffle on SSE